# DC Gain too low at higher voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, dc, gain, error

I am having an issue with DC gain for a non-inverting op amp circuit. All I am trying to do is double the voltage from two DAC outputs (DAC range is 0 to 5V and I want it to be ~0V to 10V). The DAC output is DC (<10Hz). The op amp I am using is the TI TL974 datasheet link: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl974.pdf. I am using two 1kohm resistors in my FB loop to set my gain of x2. When I input 1V and 2.5V into the op amp I get the correct values out, 2V and 5V. But when I input 5V I only get ~7.5V out. This is a rail to rail op amp and the supply voltage is 10.5V so I would expect that I should get 10V out or really close to 10V.

The output source current spec for the op amp is ~1.2mA so I thought maybe my feedback resistors are too low a value so I tried 10kohm resistors and the problem got worse, went from 7.5V out to 7V out. My load is a benchtop DMM. I attached a 10kohm resistor as the load and measured the voltage across it and things got worse again. The output voltage dropped to ~6.7V. When I just connect the DMM as the load and I set its input Z to max the voltage goes up a bit. Seems like a loading problem but if that were the case then raising the value of the feedback resistors should have helped and not made things worse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

[image]

(More traditional schematic representation shown for clarity)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1h3Bm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It took a couple of minutes to understand that your circuit was using two op-amps in non-inverting mode. Using op-amp symbols would have shown the schema instantly. TimWescott's answer is correct. Note that the datasheet only claims rail-to-rail operation at ±2.5 V. See also Figure 14 in that document. Edit: I see Tim has addressed this in your post.

Comment: I answered this and then had it pointed out to me that what I said was basically what you tried in your second paragraph, and deleted it.  It's certainly weird.  You probably don't want to use this amplifier for this application -- the input is most certainly not rail-rail, with the common-mode input range limited to being more than 1.3V away from the rails.  See Figure 18 in the data sheet.

Comment: The data sheet shows a phase margin vs. output current plot that looks distinctly weird.  Are you by chance driving a capacitive load with this?  I'm wondering if maybe it's oscillating at high output voltages.  Look at it with an O-scope & report back?

Comment: These do not support RRI nor are they Push-Pull Out so 2 reasons why you cannot use these.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXcgDr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

These are not Rail to rail input and R5 pullup to high Z internal CC source, Iol=50mA

Comment: Thanks Tony and everybody else who answered this post. In the future I need to read the datasheet a little closer. Also I will provide a better schematic for any future questions.

Comment: Did anyone understand my solution? @TimWescott ?